# ggtree issue with coloring both tips and branches

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggtree

I'm trying to make a plot using ggtree - but I'm having some issues when I try to have both the tip points and branches colored. The tree works with both of these independently, but when I try them together the `fill` for the nodes is overrided by the `color` argument from the branch and they come out grey (or it's ignoring it all together and defaulting to the same `NA` color?).

Here's the minimum code needed to produce the issue:

```
p <- ggtree(rerooted_tree, aes(color = support))
p <- p %<+% my_DF + 
  geom_tippoint(aes(fill = as.factor(domains.present)))
p
```

[image]

The variable `domains.present` is a character column in the dataframe, and works perfectly if it's `color` instead of `fill` like in the code below. In the above code, though, if `domains.present` isn't written `as.factor` within `aes` I get an error message saying `Continuous value supplied to discrete scale`.

```
q <- ggtree(rerooted_tree)
q <- q %<+% All.my_DF + 
  geom_tippoint(aes(color = domains.present), size = 1)
q
```

[image]

I'm hoping this is just a syntax issue, but I'm working on getting a reprex together to add if needed. This is a very similar issue to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63474497/ggtree-coloured-tree-branches-and-tip-points), but the OP there solved it without ggtree (I'd rather keep it simple if possible). Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue recently and having the branch colour defined outside of aes() worked for me:

```
p <- ggtree(rerooted_tree, color = support)
p <- p %<+% my_DF + 
  geom_tippoint(aes(fill = as.factor(domains.present)))
p
```